# Difference between http_proxy, https_proxy, and proxy?

Tags: npm

I'm just curious about the differences between these 3 configuration settings?

If I set `proxy` to a value, do all requests go through that or is it just HTTP and not HTTPS? Is it a catch all?

Whereas `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` are specific to the type of request? The documentation for `proxy` didn't really highlight this fact and made it sound more like an alias for `http_proxy`.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#https-proxy

> **https-proxy**
>
> - Default: null
> - Type: url
>
> A proxy to use for outgoing https requests. If the `HTTPS_PROXY` or `https_proxy` or `HTTP_PROXY` or `http_proxy` environment variables are set, proxy settings will be honored by the underlying request library.

I assume you only checked this part of the documentation: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#proxy

Comment: No, I read them all. `proxy` was confusing to me because it only explicitly states that it covers `http-proxy`. So does `https-proxy` cover all? It's difficult to tell for me. I guess I just want one value to set for all cases.

Comment: It actually depends on the usage. If you set it in config, yes it'll effect in all cases. Like this: `npm config set https-proxy protocol://domain.ext:port` and when you want to remove it, just type `npm config rm https-proxy`.